# VLOOKUPS with a date condition

Tags: vlookup, date

So I have a table with clients' names. As my team expands, some clients are shifted from one team member to another one. My table looks like this

| Starting date | End date | Client name | Team member name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | 01.03.2022 | CLIENT A | CLAIRE |
| 02.03.2022 | TODAY | CLIENT A | SOFIA |
| 01.01.2022 | TODAY | CLIENT B | CLAIRE |
| 01.01.2022 | TODAY | CLIENT C | CLAIRE |

Now, I'm doing an overview of all the clients with weekly revenue and I'd like to report which team member was responsible for the client that week. The table looks like this

| Week number | Client name | Revenues | Team member |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I cannot find how to automatically report the team member responsible for the client for that precise week base on the first table. I think it's a combination of IFS and VLOOKUPS but nothing I did worked so far.

Any hint?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Are you using Google Sheets or Excel?